# Will exporting tables in one db server to another db server release space in server?

Tags: oracle, import, export

Our production db server mount points are 95% full.There are a few tables which are not required. Hence if I export those tables to our test db server and drop those tables, will it release space in production db server?

Thanks

Comment: You may at the minimum say what database software you are using. They all have different ways to manage storage space. But generally, yes, when dropping an object, the storage space used by that object will be released. Whether that space can be reused for storing other tables depends on the RDBMS you use. Some may be unable to use it because the space is fragmented into too many small allocations. Other manage their space so that this is not an issue.

Comment: If you are looking to free space and have that space returned to the file system, that again depends on the RDBMS.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: probaply not.
Longer answer: It depends. If they have their own tablespace and you drop the tablespace also, then yes.

If your test tables are in a tablespace that holds other data and you can‘t drop it then no. The Space is freed in the tablespace itself, but not on disk. To do that you need to reorganize the tablespace.

It depends on the database version and edition if you can do this online . Another option would be to create a new tablespace, copy all objects from the old tablespace into the new one.